# Label.property reference

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I inserted a label (called Label1) in a "table cell" which in its turn is inserted into a datalist.

Why is it that in this situation, I can't use, for example, Label1.Text inside the Page_Load method, **however** when I insert the label **outside** the datalist, any reference to Label1 works perfectly?

Is there a workaround to this, as I need the label in the table cell as described and also to be able to modify its caption (.Text property) from the code-behind file, where I plan to assign it the value of a stored procedure.
Hello and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a control is inside a datalist, then it will be repeated for each item in the list. Consequently, it doesn't make sense to refer to the control outside of the datalist, as ASP.NET would not know which instance to refer to - and if there is no data, there won't even be any instances!

You can access the label given an item in the datalist, however:

```
DataListItem item = dataList.Items[0]; // or whichever item you want
Label label1 = (Label)item.FindControl("Label1");
```

Comment: Thank you, ekolis! How can I know if it's Items[0], or Items[1]. etc? Can I visually/graphically see somewhere each datalist component and its associated rank, so to speak? Maybe in the Design View? Unfortunately in Design view, I don't see anything. This is an old situation, it **doesn't** affect the site functionality, but I can't visually handle controls, except at creation, soon afterwards they disappear. I don't know of any way to restore them and I've been interested in this for a while.

Comment: In the design view, you should be able to enter template mode via an option on the right-click context menu. This will let you see the controls, as well as add more controls visually (so you don't have to do it in code).

Comment: As for Items[0] vs. Items[1], that depends entirely on your data that is bound to the datalist. Items[0] will be the item representing the first bound data item, while Items[1] will be the second, etc.

Comment: Thank you, ekolis, but I don't find "Template Mode" at all, been looking everywhere. I can right click the .ascx file and choose "View Designer", at most, which shows empty. I know for sure I have a data list there.

Comment: Also, I understand the rank depends on how the data is bound to the datalist, but what I meant earlier is that I don't remember, for example, if I have a textbox and a label, which one I placed firstly in the datalist, based on that one of the two elements will be items[0], and the other, items[1], right? So I was hoping there is **a list generated somewhere or a visual indicator to show undoubtedly the pairing of elements-rank, like: Label6 is Item[9]** etc...

Comment: No, Label6 could not be Item[9]; rather, each item contains an instance of ALL the labels, text boxes, etc. that are contained within the datalist item template. As for the designer showing empty, are you adding even the datalist itself in code?

Comment: I understand now, thank you, ekolis! As for the datalist, yes, it appears in the aspx code, as well as in the code-behind file when I specify the source and do the data binding: Datalist1.DataSource = ...; Datalist1.DataBinding(); - thus I know for certain it exists.

Comment: I forgot to add that your suggested solution worked like a charm for referencing the label!

Answer (score 2):

`Label` control is created for **every** row a `DataList` has, and it's `ID` is prefixed by every container that it is inside of (so its not called Label1 anymore) - you need to handle `OnItemCreated` or `OnItemDataBound` event, then find and cast it as `Label Label1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1")`, and only after that can you access it.

Comment: Great answer, pOcHa, thank you, I will definitely try this! It's good to be aware of several methods for the same task.